# IIS Express personalize the cmd messages

Tags: c#, iis, iis-express

When I run the iis express it displays a cmd interface where we can read all the requests that were made to the server. In fact we can see something like this :

```
Request started : "POST" "http://myWebSiteHostedIniisExpress:port/SomeAction"  
Request ended:"http://myWebSiteHostedIniisExpress:port/SomeAction" with HTTP status 200.0
```

Is it possible to personalize this kind of message? for instance to add time of the request

```
[2018/07/10 09:33] Request started : "POST" "http://myWebSiteHostedIniisExpress:port/SomeAction"  
[2018/07/10 09:33] Request ended:"http://myWebSiteHostedIniisExpress:port/SomeAction" with HTTP status 200.0
```

Comment: What is your intention behind this? Get timing information? Then trace.axd could help?

Comment: You get what you see. IIS Express is meant for development and debugging only, so there is no such fancy thing like personalization.